# How to send a proper post request to WHMCS installation from android app?

Tags: java, android, http, request, whmcs

I am trying to send an AddClient post request to my WHMCS installation through my android app but it keeps returning "result=error;message=You did not enter your first name".

I get it to authenticate successfully but it doesnt seem to be posting the jsonObject I am sending it.

Here is a link to WHMCS api documentation: https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/addclient/

```
public void createWHMCSUser(final String emailID, final String random, final String uid) {

    final String AccessUserKey = "abc123";
    final String AccessKey = "abc123";
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://whmcs.installation.com/includes/api.php?action=AddClient&username=abc123&password=abc123&accesskey=abc123");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("action", "AddClient");
                jsonParam.put("identifier", AccessUserKey);
                jsonParam.put("secret", AccessKey);
                jsonParam.put("firstname", "User");
                jsonParam.put("lastname", "Name");
                jsonParam.put("email", emailID);
                jsonParam.put("address1", "na");
                jsonParam.put("city", "na");
                jsonParam.put("state", "na");
                jsonParam.put("postcode", "00000");
                jsonParam.put("country", "US");
                jsonParam.put("phonenumber", "0000000000");
                jsonParam.put("password2", random);
                jsonParam.put("repsonsetype", "json");

                Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                //os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());



                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    thread.start();

}
```

It should return "result=success".

But actually returns "result=error;message=You did not enter your first name".

Answer (score 0):

It’s seems your API doesn’t work in this sample.

try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and if json doesn’t work there, issue is in your api.